# Is it possible to convert a Geoserver SLD to Quantum QML format?

Tags: qgis, geoserver, convert, sld

I have a web application which runs on Geoserver. I am migrating my application to desktop and am struck at applying the same color schemes and symbology. I am not able to find a way to convert SLDs to QML for implementing in desktop application.

I am aware that Quantum GIS 1.8 has the SLD input in styling. I specifically need a solution for Quantum GIS 1.6, as it is more preferred in my organization. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use QGIS1.8 to convert SLD to QML and test if they can be opened in QGIS1.6.

Note though that there are some issues using QML created from newer versions in older ones. But they mostly concern labeling.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried opening it from 1.6, it opened fine. But the whole symbology has changed.

Comment: Maybe the SLD is not compatible. Was it fine in 1.8? Can you show what went wrong?